# Compare Two dataframes add mis matched values as a new column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, compare, addition, difference

Difference between two records is:

```
df1.except(df2)
```

Its getting results like this

[image]

How to compare two dataframes and what changes, and where & which column have changes, add this value as a column. Expected output like this

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to create the content of column **remarks**? If so, can you show the content of that column fully?

Comment: except is a kind of minus operation. I would suggest to add some example in the question that helps people to understand and answer better.

Comment: Let eg:, in old data, 
firstname, lastname, address not matching with new data. give this information in remarks column. <br/> let eg: in old data james, new data nitin. Now get this info as firstname not matching.. At the same time compare second column column. Give this info also in the same column.

Answer (score 2):

Join the two dataframe on the primary key, later using a with column and UDF pass the both column values(old and new values), in UDF compare the data and return the value if not same.

```
val check = udf ( (old_val:String,new_val:String) => if (old_val == new_val) new_val else "")

df_check= df
   .withColumn("Check_Name",check(df.col("name"),df.col("new_name")))
   .withColumn("Check_Namelast",check(df.col("lastname"),df.col("new_lastname")))
```

Or Def function

```
            def fn(old_df:Dataframe,new_df:Dataframe) : Dataframe = 
            {
            val old_df_array = old_df.collect() //make df to array to loop thru
            val new_df_array = new_df.collect() //make df to array to loop thru
            var value_change : Array[String] = ""

            val count = old_df.count
            val row_count = old_df.coloumn
            val row_c = row.length
            val coloumn_name = old_df.coloumn

            for (i to count ) //loop thru all rows
            {
            var old = old_df_array.Map(x => x.split(","))
            var new = new_df_array.Map(x => x.split(","))
            for (j to row_c ) //loop thru all coloumn
            {
            if( old(j) !=  new(j) )
            {
            value_change  = value_change + coloumn_name(j) " has value changed" ///this will add all changes in one full row
            }
            //append to array 
            append j(0) //primary key
            append value_change //Remarks coloumn
            }
            }
            //convert array to df
            }
```